# How to make a UITableView height dynamic to a specific height and and then allow scrolling without using AutolayOut in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to make a tableview height dynamic (based on number of cells loaded) to a specific limit. and after reaching that limit I want to make UITableView scrollable. I do not want use autolayout for this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrScreenTime.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrScreenTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kRobotoRegular size:25];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = kColor(2, 109, 150, 1);

    UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    customColorView.backgroundColor = kColor(53, 144, 177, 1);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;

    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = kColor(255, 255, 255, 1);

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [arrScreenTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:kRobotoRegular size:25];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSLog(@"height=%f",labelSize.height);
    return labelSize.height + 8;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       CGFloat tableHeight = 0.0f;

       float baseHeightofTableView = tblViewTitle.frame.size.height;

   NSLog(@"baseHeightofTableView = %f",baseHeightofTableView);


        for (int i = 0; i < [arrScreenTime count]; i++) {

            tableHeight += [self tableView:tblViewTitle heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        }

        tblViewTitle.frame = CGRectMake(tblViewTitle.frame.origin.x, tblViewTitle.frame.origin.y, tblViewTitle.frame.size.width, tableHeight);

        NSLog(@"tblViewTitle.frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(tblViewTitle.frame));

        tblViewTitle.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                          self.frame.size.height / 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code,

```
if ([rowCount] > 5) { // 5 is the specific limit to which you wanted to increase table height and after that it goes in else part to not increase the height of tableview instead it will make tableview scrollable.
    tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.tableview.frame.size.width, 5 * [height of row]);
} else {
    tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableview.frame.size.width, [rowCount] * 50);
}
```

Replace rowCount and height of row based on your requirement.

Hope it will help you out! 
Cheers

Comment: But cell height is not fixed.Height of  cell is also dynamic.  then it will not fullfilll, the contion

Comment: Only text is there in your cell? Or anything else?

Comment: Yes,content is only text based.

Comment: @AdityaYadav calculate the text height and set the height of cell according to the text height.

Comment: @AdityaYadav Yes please add your tableview related code so we can help you in some better way!

Comment: @AdityaYadav So you can do one thing, in willDisplayCell: method inside your for loop. You can add one if else condition. If (tableHeight > Your defined value(like [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)) { tableHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height } else { tableHeight += [self tableView:tblViewTitle heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]; }

Comment: Thanks,@ Gati, I got the idea..       I have used this code snippet and its working fine  float baseHeightofTableView = tblViewTitle.frame.size.height;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < [arrBasics count]; i++)
        {
            if (tableHeight < baseHeightofTableView) {
                
               tableHeight += [self tableView:tblViewTitle heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            }
            else{
                tableHeight = baseHeightofTableView;
                
                break;
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

I have implimented this code snippet and it is working fine for me..

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrBasics.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrBasics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kRobotoRegular size:25];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = kColor(2, 109, 150, 1);

    UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    customColorView.backgroundColor = kColor(53, 144, 177, 1);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;

    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = kColor(255, 255, 255, 1);

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [arrBasics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:kRobotoRegular size:25];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSLog(@"height=%f",labelSize.height);
    return labelSize.height + 8;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       CGFloat tableHeight = 0.0f;

       float baseHeightofTableView = tblViewTitle.frame.size.height;

        for (int i = 0; i < [arrBasics count]; i++)
        {
            if (tableHeight < baseHeightofTableView) {

               tableHeight += [self tableView:tblViewTitle heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            }
            else{
                tableHeight = baseHeightofTableView;

                break;
            }
        }

        tblViewTitle.frame = CGRectMake(tblViewTitle.frame.origin.x, tblViewTitle.frame.origin.y, tblViewTitle.frame.size.width, tableHeight);

        NSLog(@"tblViewTitle.frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(tblViewTitle.frame));

        tblViewTitle.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                          self.frame.size.height / 2);

}
```